# How to update a dictionary in a file with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, file, dictionary

I'm trying to get a dictionary from a file, add some data to it and save it back to the same file. When I run the program, it always goes to except after it prints 1 and loops like that forever. How can I fix it?

This is the data I pass to the function(this is sample data - I actually pass a password and an username encrypted with a random key):
key: '␙⋉∡'
value: ['␙⋉∡➵ᾁ\u1fd5ᾁ', 84, None]}
file_name: 'database.database'

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Currently_Working_On\Database_Login_Chat.py", line 46, in write_data
    file_data = eval(file_data)
  File "<string>", line 0
    
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Currently_Working_On\Database_Login_Chat.py", line 52, in write_data
    file2.write(str(file_data))
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 2-3: character maps to <undefined>
```

```
def write_data(key, value, file_name):
    try:
        file = open(file_name, "r")
        file_data = str(file.read())
        file.close()

        file_data = eval(file_data)
        file_data[key] = value

        file_data = str(file_data)
        file2 = open(file_name, "w")
        print("1")
        file2.write(str(file_data))
        print("2")
        file2.close()
        print("3")
    except:
        file3 = open(file_name, "w")
        file3.write("{}")
        file3.close()
        print("0")
        write_data(key, value, file_name)
```

Comment: What means "crashes"? If there is an error message show it completely as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: It exits the try, goes to except and loops forever.

Comment: (1) You shouldn't call the function itself in the exception handling. If it failed once it will also fail twice or more often. (2) You shouldn't just catch all possible exceptions in a large code block. (3) Import "traceback" and execute "traceback.print_exc()" at beginning of the "except" block to retrieve information what exactly went wrong.

Comment: If you want to store a dict into a file, you should use JSON (or YAML, or pickle)

Comment: This is the error it returns.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Currently_Working_On\Database_Login_Chat.py", line 46, in write_data
    file_data = eval(file_data)
  File "<string>", line 0
    
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Currently_Working_On\Database_Login_Chat.py", line 52, in write_data
    file2.write(str(file_data))
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 2-3: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Show it as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: (1) As @Corralien already mentioned there are many better ways to store a dictionary. (2) Using "eval" is dangerous, for simple cases try "ast.literal_eval" instead. (3) You should specify a suitable "encoding" (usually "utf-8") when you "open" a file to avoid the "UnicodeEncodeError".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass thru encoding error try to specify encoding parameter to all read and write parts of your code like this:

```
...
file = open(file_name, "r", encoding='utf-8')
...
file2 = open(file_name, "w", encoding='utf-8')
...
file3 = open(file_name, "w", encoding='utf-8')
...
```

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. I just specified the encoding as you suggested and now it works. Thanks.